Are electrons in CRT classical objects?
Electrons in CRT seem to behave like classical objects with well-defined classical trajectories. But at the same time, it's elementary particles living in quantum world with weird quantum rules. How these electrons lose their quantum properties, or how this really works?

You can get some idea of how an electron in a CRT beam is described by comparing it to the classical description of a laser beam.
For convenience we'll take the laser beam to be along the $x$ axis so it has a well defined $p_x$ component of momentum. To a good approximation it's an infinite plane wave propagating along the $x$ axis. Its momenta in the $y$ and $z$ directions is zero on average, but there is some uncertainty in this because the beam will diffract and spread outwards in the radial direction (forming an Airy disk).
The CRT generates an electron beam much like a laser beam. The electrons in the beam have a well defined energy, and therefore a well defined momentum and de Broglie wavelength in the direction of the beam. However the beam should not be thought of as stream of little balls because the electrons will be delocalised along the length of the beam. Their position measured along the beam is not well defined until they hit the screen and the interaction with the screen localises them. Even if we reduce the beam intensity to the point where only one electron at a time is in transit to the screen that electron remains spread out along the beam.
Like the laser beam the electrons do have a well defined position normal to the beam, with an associated uncertainty in the momentum normal to the beam. However in a CRT the beam radius in normally not small enough to create a large uncertainty.
So the bottom line is that the electrons in the beam are behaving much like free particles and are described by the free particle solutions to the Schrodinger equation.

What's confusing me - what if we move a screen nearer and nearer to the electron gun? We'll see classical trajectory that way, isn't it?
